Forcing HAProxy to send HTTP 1.1 requests to backend server
I'm serving some legacy clients that support only HTTP/1.0. The min version that the backend server accepts is HTTP/1.1.
I'm trying to configure HAProxy so that it receives HTTP/1.0 requests and then send them as HTTP/1.1 request to the backend server.
I've tested some simple configuration in HAProxy that should work, but when I send HTTP/1.0 requests to HAProxy with CURL, I keep getting the response code "426 Upgrade Required" from the backend server. Apparently HAProxy keeps sending requests as HTTP/1.0 to the backend server.
This is my HAProxy config:
global
log 127.0.0.1 local2
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn 40000
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog
option dontlognull
option http-server-close
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
option redispatch
retries 3
timeout http-request 10s
timeout queue 1m
timeout connect 10s
timeout client 1m
timeout server 1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check 10s
maxconn 15000

listen farm_ssfti
bind *:50121
http-request replace-header Host .* ssfti.test.io
default-server check ssl verify none alpn http/1.1,h2
server ssfpi ssfpi.server.io:443

Should this work? Is it even possible to receive requests with version 1.0 and send them to the backend server in version 1.1?
Thanks!

try proto h1 http://docs.haproxy.org/3.0/configuration.html#5.1-proto

Thanks for your reply! I've tried this. This configuration would work to force the protocol version for the frontend, not the backend. Also, this would work only when not using SSL.
